# ¿Como obtener datos entre un rango de fechas usando MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda y es que quiero realizar una consulta entre dos fechas consultando a la misma columna que es `Fecha`, la consulta siguiente sí me realiza dicha búsqueda:

```
SELECT *
FROM   view_listservicios a
       JOIN rel_franquiciaslavadores b
         ON a.idlavador = b.idlavador
WHERE  a.estatus = 'Finalizado'
       AND fecha >= '2017-02-01'
       AND a.fecha <= '2017-02-09'
ORDER  BY idtab_serviciolavado ASC
```

Por el contrario, si aplico esa misma consulta pero utilizando el mismo día `Fecha >= '2017-02-09' AND Fecha <= '2017-02-09'` no me retorna nada.

Ya he utilizado el `BETWEEN` pero aun así no consigo el resultado deseado.

Comment: Que tipo de columna tiene definido "Fecha"?

Comment: El tipo de dato es "DATETIME"

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de obtener algún resultado en la otra consulta que tenga la fecha `2017-02-09`?

Comment: Si, si obtengo otros resultados, solo puse de ejemplo ese fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy posiblemente te falte indicar las horas. Para que se realice la consulta entre estas dos fechas.

```
SELECT *
FROM   view_listservicios a
       JOIN rel_franquiciaslavadores b
         ON a.idlavador = b.idlavador
WHERE  a.estatus = 'Finalizado'
       AND fecha >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
       AND a.fecha <= '2017-02-09 23:59:59'
ORDER  BY idtab_serviciolavado ASC
```

Comment: Es correcto, faltarían las horas. SQL pone por default las horas en `00:00:00:000`. Entonces a lo mejor solo sería cuestión de asignarle las horas al segundo valor de fecha.

Comment: Colocando un rango de fechas como tu me indicaste `Fecha >= '2017-02-09 00:00:00' AND Fecha <= '2017-02-09 23:59:00'`, el resultado ya es el deseado

Answer (score 2):

En casos de columnas del tipo de datos `DATETIME`, siempre es importante considerar la hora. Cuando escribes  `2017-02-09`, al no especificar la hora en verdad estás diciendo `2017-02-09 00:00:00.00`.

De esta forma, es fácil ver que:

```
Fecha >= '2017-02-09 00:00:00.00' 
AND Fecha <= '2017-02-09 00:00:00.00'
```

Es lo mismo que decir:

```
WHERE Fecha = '2017-02-09 00:00:00.00'
```

Lo que es muy fácil que no te entregue resultados.
Te recomiendo que en estos casos uses menor estricto que el día siguiente en vez de `<=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   view_listservicios a
       JOIN rel_franquiciaslavadores b
         ON a.idlavador = b.idlavador
WHERE  a.estatus = 'Finalizado'
       AND fecha >= '2017-02-01'
       AND a.fecha < '2017-02-10'
ORDER  BY idtab_serviciolavado ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) para convertir a `date` el valor de la columna `datetime`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM   view_listservicios a
   JOIN rel_franquiciaslavadores b
     ON a.idlavador = b.idlavador
WHERE  a.estatus = 'Finalizado'
   AND DATE(a.date) BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-09'
```

Answer (score 1):

Por qué si estás usando el campo Fecha de la misma tabla en una sí la referencías y en la que te devuelve nada no la referencías? Si en ambas tablas tienes un campo Fecha hay ambiguedad y tal vez por eso no te regresa nada.

```
AND Fecha >= '2017-02-01' AND a.Fecha <= '2017-02-09' //Sí regresa
AND Fecha >= '2017-02-01' AND Fecha <= '2017-02-09' //No regresa
```

Me hubiera gustado comentar eso en vez de postearlo como respuesta pero aún no tengo la reputación necesaria.

Comment: El campo "a.Fecha" es el mismo, el la tabla View_listServicios solo existe ese campo

Comment: Entonces utiliza el formato completo de un DATETIME, especificando la fecha y la hora